# What is the behaviour of water at a pressure reducing valve (PRV)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, pressure, refrigeration

Suppose I pass water through a pressure reducing valve, which can lower the pressure enough for the water to boil, will the water **fully** boil? If so, what would happen if that vapour passed to a tube, for instance, with atmospheric pressure? Will the water return to the liquid state? If it returns back to liquid, how do I sustain the vapour state?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The water might boil if pressure is reduced below the vapor pressure of the water.  That means the outlet of the PRV must be at a low pressure.

Boiling water at normal temps requires a **very** low pressure.  Just a reducing valve won't be enough, you will need to induce vacuum at the exit.  At room temp, this is around 1/20 of an atmosphere.  Doing this through a valve will likely result in freezing; you still have to remove the heat from the liquid, and the most likely mechanism for this is through freezing.

If you mean a momentary flashing to vapor going through a throttle or such, this will likely only be some of the water, and it will immediately condense back to liquid when the high velocity-low pressure condition is no longer there.